# How can I use an array or another approach to improve since this list will grow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works but will quickly be inefficient (already so?) as my var list grows.

I am adding Twitter streams to pages with their new API. That means I need to provide them some info manually and they return an ID string. That's OK, no workaround.

This example uses the info I need for just three streams but the list will quickly grow to dozens or even more.

```
function isValidTweets(ts_titletweets) {
    var widgetid = $('#TweetStuff').attr('data-widget-id');

    var jackID = '243441836335697920'; //IDs associated with streams
    var jillID = '243398621595312128';
    var harryID = '243398621595312130';


    var ts_titletweets = title.toLowerCase(); //title is parsed from URL elsewhere
    validtweets = "jack|jill|harry"; // if the title doesn't match then no streams should be used
    if (validtweets.indexOf(ts_titletweets.toLowerCase() + "|") > -1) {

        console.log('TweetsEnabled');

        if (ts_titletweets == "jack")
        {widgetid = jackID;
        console.log(widgetid + title)}
        else if (ts_titletweets == "jill")
        {widgetid = jillID;
        console.log(widgetid + title)}
        else if (ts_titletweets == "harry")
        {widgetid = harryID;
        console.log(widgetid + title)};


        $('#TweetStuff').html("<a class=\"twitter-timeline\" width=\"500\" height=\"600\" data-widget-id=" + widgetid + "></a>");

        $("#newTweetsButton").delay(3000).show(0);
        $("#filters").css({'margin' : '-30px 0px 0px 0px'});
        return true;

    } console.log('no Tweets'); 
    return false;

}
```

I'm certain I'm manually reentering and want to avoid that as the list grows.

Any and all suggestions are much appreciated for a grateful newbie.

Thanks!

**UPDATED TYPOS**

Comment: Where do `fooID`, `longreadsID` and `thinkprogressID` come from?

Comment: Sorry, cut & paste error from longer list. Will revise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an object that has properties that correspond to the person's name. You then store the id against that. Next you can check whether it exists and execute your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/7PSNt/1/

```
var title = 'jill'; //hard coded for demo purposes
var myObject = {
    'jack': 1,
    'jill': 2,
    'harry': 3
};

//I assume title is just one of the keys above (jack, jill, harry)                 
var ts_titletweets = title.toLowerCase();

//if the object contains a property for the title then we can proceed
var tweetID = myObject[ts_titletweets];
if (tweetID != undefined) {
    widgetid = tweetID;
    console.log(widgetid + ':' + title)
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks! Have integrated your suggestion with the actual code (versus example posted) and appears to be good. Will continue to test. I like the object approach since it appears to be easily extended to JSON (?). I will attempt the efficiency recs that Beetroot-Beetroot suggested next.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what's going on in the code, but what you could be using is a lookup-table.

```
    var ids = {
        'jack': '243441836335697920',
        'jill': '243398621595312128',
        'harry': '243398621595312130'
    };


    if (/*whatever*/) {

        widgetid = ids[ts_titletweets];
        console.log(widgetid + title);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are asking, but here's some stuff that might help:

```
// define an object with name: id pairs
var twitterIds = {
  'jack': '243441836335697920',
  'jill': '243398621595312128',
  'harry': '243398621595312130'
};

foreach(var name in twitterIds) {
  // name = jack
  // twitterIds[name] = '243441836335697920'
}

function loadTweets ( name ) {
  if( name && twitterIds[name] ) {
    // load stream here.  Use twitterIds[name] to get the twitter id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, try this:

```
//cache of static jQuery objects
var $$ = { 
    'TweetStuff': $('#TweetStuff'),
    'newTweetsButton': $("#newTweetsButton"),
    'filters': $("#filters")
};

//define the ids in an outer scope - this gives isValidTweets less work to do each time it is called
var ids = {
    jack: '243441836335697920',
    jill: '243398621595312128',
    harry: '243398621595312130'
};

function isValidTweets(title) {
    var t = title.toLowerCase();
    var widgetid = ids[t] || $$.TweetStuff.attr('data-widget-id');
    $$.TweetStuff.html("<a class=\"twitter-timeline\" width=\"500\" height=\"600\" data-widget-id=" + widgetid + "></a>");
    $$.newTweetsButton.delay(3000).show(0);
    $$.filters.css({'margin' : '-30px 0px 0px 0px'});
    console.log('Tweets: ' + (ids[t] ? (widgetid + ' - ' + title) : 'none')); 
    return !!ids[t];//true or false
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this to work too with a couple of mods. I will edit your code to illustrate and let me know if there is another approach. I cannot change the name of the function since it is named elsewhere.

Comment: I don't understand, there's no change to the function name in my code. I changed isValidTweets' formal parameter to `(title)` because the line `var ts_titletweets = title.toLowerCase();` makes a nonsense of the formal parameter being `(ts_titletweets)`. If `title` is in an outer scope, then the function doesn't need anything passed to it.

Comment: Not sure. Perhaps because the function is called from another page as `$.isValidTumbyTweets(ts_titletweets);` This code resides in its own .js file.